# Getting the time property of an audio file in java

Tags: java, audio

Read an audio file, for example a wav file, then get its time length. Then get its bytes value from second by second, or by half a second. Like I have a 20 seconds wav and i will output its bytes[] by the time I specified. Because getting the bytes for all the length of the file takes very large of space.

This is me getting the bytes from the audio file, but i need just the bytes by its seconds. Any help?

```
    FileInputStream s = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/audio_raw.wav");
    BufferedInputStream b = new BufferedInputStream(s);
    byte[] data = new byte[128];

    while((bytes = b.read(data)) > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<bytes; i++)
        {
            unsigned = data[i] & 0xFF;
            bw.write(unsigned+"+");
        }
    }

    b.read(data);
    b.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function from a class that processes WAV files I use. You can see how it reads in the file and can extract some data about the WAV file. Perhaps it can assist you:

```
// read a wav file into this class
public boolean read()
{
    DataInputStream inFile = null;
    myData = null;
    byte[] tmpLong = new byte[4];
    byte[] tmpInt = new byte[2];

    try
    {
        inFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(myPath));

        //System.out.println("Reading wav file...\n"); // for debugging only

        String chunkID = "" + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the ChunkSize
        myChunkSize = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);

        String format = "" + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();

        // print what we've read so far
        //System.out.println("chunkID:" + chunkID + " chunk1Size:" + myChunkSize + " format:" + format); // for debugging only



        String subChunk1ID = "" + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the SubChunk1Size
        mySubChunk1Size = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the audio format.  This should be 1 for PCM
        myFormat = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the # of channels (1 or 2)
        myChannels = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the samplerate
        mySampleRate = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the byterate
        myByteRate = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the blockalign
        myBlockAlign = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        inFile.read(tmpInt); // read the bitspersample
        myBitsPerSample = byteArrayToInt(tmpInt);

        // print what we've read so far
        //System.out.println("SubChunk1ID:" + subChunk1ID + " SubChunk1Size:" + mySubChunk1Size + " AudioFormat:" + myFormat + " Channels:" + myChannels + " SampleRate:" + mySampleRate);


        // read the data chunk header - reading this IS necessary, because not all wav files will have the data chunk here - for now, we're just assuming that the data chunk is here
        String dataChunkID = "" + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte() + (char) inFile.readByte();

        inFile.read(tmpLong); // read the size of the data
        myDataSize = byteArrayToLong(tmpLong);


        // read the data chunk
        myData = new byte[(int) myDataSize];
        inFile.read(myData);

        // close the input stream
        inFile.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true; // this should probably be something more descriptive
}
```

Comment: this might, thanks! gonna play with it now. let you know if it did the trick.